# when to pass a pointer argument to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a little confused about this. My professor told me that when you want something to *change* you pass a pointer. I understood it with example of `swap(&first_number, &second_number)`. Also,
I know that I don't need a pointer for a function that returns maximum of two integers , because I can send copy of two integers and function can easily return the maximum.
But I am confused about this:

```
void f(int a[], int *n)
{
    a[3] = a[(*n)-1];
    (*n)--;
}
```

This works well.  How can I be 100% sure when to pass `int *a[]` or just `int a[]`?

Comment: `int a[]` is an array of `int`, `int *a[]` is an array of `int *`. here is the difference. symbol `[]` is essentially identical to `*` in type system of C. so if you say you are passing an array to a function, you could say you are passing the pointer too.

Comment: I don't get your confusion (the explanation in the first paragraph sounds like you've already understood the concept). Maybe you can elaborate on how you'd expect `f` to be written instead? And where comes this `int *a[]` from?

Comment: In a parameter declaration -- and *only* in a parameter declaration -- `int a[]` really means `int *a`. In any other contexts, arrays and pointers are absolutely *not* the same thing. Array expressions are converted to pointers in most contexts. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) explains this.

Comment: @mafso; If you really do not understand a question then do not downvote to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used as formal parameters to a function, `int a[]` and `int *a` are equivalent.

Here is an example - compiles cleanly on gcc 4.8

```
void foo(int *a) {
}

void bar(int a[]) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int value;
  int array[2] = {1,2};

  foo(&value);
  foo(array);

  bar(&value);
  bar(array);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My professor told me that when you want something to change you pass a pointer.

This means that if you want changes to be seen in variable declared in calling function then you need to pass the pointer to that variable to the called function provided the called function expects pointer to variable as an argument.

When array name is passed to a function as an argument then array names converted to a pointer to its first element. In case when used as function parameters `int a[]` and `int *a` are equivalent.

```
void f(int a[], int *n)
```

is equivalent to

```
void f(int *a, int *n)
```

So, you do not need `int *a[]` .

Comment: Why a third answer repeating the part OP already understands?

Comment: @mafso; Where it is repeated?

Comment: Yes, sorry, no repetition. Maybe it's really the array-to-pointer decay OP doesn't understand. But then, the `int *a[]` would be a typo and it should be clarified before (and if this is the confusion, finding a duplicate would do it).

Comment: @mafso; Finding a duplicate is another issue and should not be related to the downvote.

Comment: The duplicate can be found when the question is clear, and this is indeed unrelated to voting here. If your answer happens to answer the clarified question, I'll be happy to retract my vote.

Comment: What does OP think `int *[]` is good for here? What doesn't OP understand about the `f` function?

Comment: But be it as it may, I'm not going to spend more time here. I don't want to read all the other answers... Retracted the vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
int * a[] - means array of pointers  
          - so each index will store pointer type variable
```

eg:

```
int *arr[2];
int a=10,b=20;
int *ptr1=&a;
int *ptr2=&b;
arr[0]=ptr1;
arr[1]=ptr2;

printf("%d",*arr[0]);--->10
printf("%d",*arr[1]);--->20
```

where as

```
int a[]- array of integers 
         also can be said as pointer to an array
```

eg :

```
int arr[]={10,20};
printf("%d",*arr)--->10
```

so when u want to pass array to function use int * **var** or int **var** []
  and when you want to pass array which has pointer variable as elements then use int * **var** []

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you pass the parameters in a function call:

1. By value, which is only possible for primitive types such as int, byte, char, etc.
2. By reference, by which you in fact pass the location in memory.

The last one is automatically used for non-primitive types (such as arrays), so no '*' is needed; the value is in memory and you provide a reference to this block of memory.
`int a[]` will therefore point to the array in memory. Passing by value means that the value of the variable you pass is copied to a local variable in the method. Changing that local variable will have no effect on the source variable. If you pass it by reference (int* n) you can change the source variable.
Passing `int* a[]` would be a reference to an array of pointers to int's, which you don't want in your case.

You can however point to the first element of the array by using `int* a` instead of `int a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to use a[3] directly without knowing the length of your array, that can be produce a Segmentation fault if your array is smaller than 4 int. The best way for avoid this behaviour, it's to pass the length of your array in params of your function.

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question.